# How to adjust the position of items in the Package Explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Currently, my "Package Explorer" in Eclipse shows as follows:

[image]

I want to move the "src" folder to the top of "JRE System Library".

How should I do to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the displayed elements is **given by the order of the elements in the `.classpath`** file.

To move the source folder `src` to the top, open the `.classpath` file (which is only visible in the *Navigator* view) and move the following line up so that it is the first child element of the `<classpath>` element:

```xml
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But every time a new project is created, its structure is the same as mentioned above. How to modify the global configuration?

Comment: @skyclouder As far as I know, there is no global configuration for that. You could report it as a feature request to Eclipse or write a plug-in yourself.